# How to check undefined 2d array value without getting 'Cannot check undefined property' errors

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

As you can see, after creating the 2d array with [20][20] length, there is a if statement trying to check if the array value is 'undefined'; however, somehow, I'm keep getting errors saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined".
So, is there a way to avoid getting error and check if there is a value.

```js
//If there is a more efficiency way to build these loops, then I'll be glad to see it

let map = [];
let savedPoints = [];
let value = 0;
let something = 0; // testing values
let somethingelse = 0; 

for(let i = 0 ; i < 20; i++) {
  map[i] = [];
  savedPoints[i] = [];
  let pointx = i + something;
  for(let j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
    let pointy = j + somethingelse;
    savedPoints[i][j] = {pointx, pointy};
    map[i][j] = value;
  }
}

let x = 110;
let y = 0;
//this will give error
if(typeof map[x+1][y] !== 'undefined') { 
  //do something... 
}
```

Comment: `Cannot read property '0' of undefined"` doesn't mean that the array value is undefined. It means that the thing you are trying to get the value from is. Essentially, what you believe is an array isn't at the time you are trying to access it.

Comment: why should map[111] not be undefined in your opinion? If it is undefined, what do you think undefined[0] should do?

Comment: Please edit your post so that the code will produce the same results that you are saying you get.

Comment: typeof map[111] wont give an error, but typeof map[111][0] will give an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
if (typeof map[x+1] !== 'undefined' && typeof map[x+1][y] !== 'undefined') {
 //code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check first array with

```
if(map[x+1]) { 
  //do something... 
}
```

and check 2d array with

```
if(map[x+1]) {
  if(map[x+1][y]) { 
    //do something... 
  }
}
```

Comment: it one with map[x+1][y] did not work, map[x+1] worked, but I want to check [y] values too

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (map[x+1] && map[x+1][y]) { ... }
```

You don't need `typeof` map can contain only arrays. If `map[x+1]` equal to false `map[x+1][y]` will not be checked. Looks not good. Wait chain checks in new standarts.

Comment: map[x+1] worked, but with map[x+1][y]  it did not, for some reason it's not checking the [y] value